# C get and instantiate struct type from array of different structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having trouble figuring this out...

I have a bunch of structs defining message types from a data stream that look like this:

```
struct QM_lUpdP
{
    char type [6];
    char exchange_id [6];
    char currency_id [4];
    char hour [3];
    char minute [3];
    char second [3];
    char millisecond [4];
    char instrument_type [3];
    char order_reference [31];
    char price_type [2];
    char price [11];
    char mmid [5];

} QM_lUpdP;
```

There are many of them with different names and formats.

What I want to be able to do is... dynamically, given a struct name, get and instantiate that struct, so far I'm doing this..

```
char data_struct_names[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES + 1][16] = {
    "QM_BkCan",
    "QM_BkChg",
    "QM_BkDel",
    "QM_BkExc",
     ...
    "QM_lEquI",
};

void * QM_get_data_struct (char * struct_name)
{
    void * data_structs [NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES + 1] = {
        &QM_BkCan,
        &QM_BkChg,
        &QM_BkDel,
        &QM_BkExc,
        ...
        &QM_lEquI
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(data_struct_names[i], struct_name) == 0) return data_structs[i];
    }

    fprintf( stderr, "%s is an invalid or unimplemented struct!!\n", struct_name);
    return (void *)0;
}
```

So, given a name, we can search through the list of names, find the index, and then grab that struct from the list of structs that has identical indexes.

Right now, I'm just returning a void pointer, which returns a reliable address depending on the struct. Is there a way to unwrap this pointer and use it as a struct?

...how to instantiate it and use it in code. Is this even possible because the type of struct is not known so I can't just do...

```
QM_BkCan data = QM_get_data_struct("BkCan");
```

Is this even possible? Is there a different way I should be approaching this?

```
Ideally I would have...

data_struct = get_struct(NAME_STRING);

data_struct.value = "hello!";

printf("%s", data_struct.value); // hello!
```

Thank you.

Comment: @DavidBowling let me see if I can explain: I start with an arbitrary message  STRING that could have any of a set of types. I find the type from this string. Next, I want to get a struct that represents this message type and instantiate it with values parsed from the message. The main problem is that I can't know before hand what struct type I need to use, so it needs to be found using the TYPE STRING found from the message. Does that make sense?... message string -> get type -> get struct -> parse message and populate struct with values... if that's unclear I can put together a better code ex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting isn't possible in C.

I think you might need to do this a different way. You could do something like:

```
struct QM_BkCan {
    ...
}
struct QM_BkChg {
    ...
}
struct QM_BkDel {
    ...
}
struct QM_BkExc {
    ...
}
struct QM_lEquI {
    ...
}

enum QM_Types {
    QM_Type_BkCan = 0,
    QM_Type_BkChg,
    QM_Type_BkDel,
    QM_Type_BkExc,
    QM_Type_lEquI
}

union QM_Structs {
    struct QM_BkCan QM_BkCan;
    struct QM_BkChg QM_BkChg;
    struct QM_BkDel QM_BkDel;
    struct QM_BkExc QM_BkExc;
    struct QM_lEquI QM_lEquI;
}
```

As you need to use a dynamic string, you can use your function (but modified):

```
char data_struct_names[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES + 1][16] = {
    "QM_BkCan",
    "QM_BkChg",
    "QM_BkDel",
    "QM_BkExc",
    "QM_lEquI",
};

enum QM_Types QM_get_data_struct (char * struct_name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(data_struct_names[i], struct_name) == 0)
            return (enum QM_Types)((int)QM_Type_BkCan + i);
    }

    fprintf( stderr, "%s is an invalid or unimplemented struct!!\n", struct_name);
    return (void *)0;
}
```

Then, you can use it as follows:

```
struct QM_Structs * s = (QM_Structs *)your_data_array;

switch (QM_get_data_struct(YOUR_STRING)) {
    case QM_Type_BkCan:
        s->QM_BkCan.something = something_else;
        break;
    case QM_Type_BkChg:
        s->QM_BkChg.something = something_else;
        break;
    ...
}
```

It's not a very nice way of doing it, but I don't believe there is any other way.

Comment: Possibly! Sorry I'm a bit of a noob, can you give me a code example of how this would work? The hardest part seems to be the last part... Once I actually get the struct, how do I instantiate it without knowing its type beforehand?

Also, on the note of maintainability and portability, i have scripts generating all the code that defines these structures, so It's adapt if things change.

Comment: I'm on my phone atm, I'll post a possible solution soon

Comment: thank you! anything will be illuminating I imagine. To clarify, I want a function GET_DATA_STRUCT(struct_name) that gives me a struct of that type I can eventually set/access. No worries if not a full answer, but anything helps

Comment: so type, is the struct I want to use now? The only reason this doesn't seem to work is because I need to get the type from a dynamic string. And where is the union even used? I don't see `structs` anywhere.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a possible solution but I'm not fully sure why you need to use a dynamic string to find a structure...?

Comment: You've made me realize that there is a much simpler solution... that there doesn't need to be anything dynamic about it... its outside of the scope of this question though. I was way over thinking this. Thank you for being thorough it taught me some valuable things.